# Install sharp without GitHub fetch for Nextjs: Error: Cannot find module 'sharp'

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, sharp, nextjs-image

I'm trying to use Next.js on my corporate system, but whenever I run "npm run build", the build fails with the message: `Error: Cannot find module 'sharp'`

I tried installing sharp but I get this error:

```
info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.5/libvips-8.10.5-win32-x64.tar.br 
ERR! sharp getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com 
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
```

This is probably because github URLs are blocked on my system's terminal due to security reasons. Is there a way to install sharp without fetching from github? I can access GitHub on the browser, so if downloading the file from there and then installing it somehow is possible I can do that.

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE**: **NextJS [`v10.0.8`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v10.0.8) fixes [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22253)**! If you're running into the above error: upgrade to the 10.0.8 (or beyond).

The required `sharp` dependency introduced with NextJS `10.0.5` has broken builds that depend on the underlying libvips, which isn't there in various Linux distros. They're working on making the dependency optional. Relevant PR [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/21762) and [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/20738). Related issue [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20456). This may be easier than trying to get libvips installed or compiled on your machine (I simply couldn't get it to work on my Amazon EC2 ARM-based machine). You can downgrade to NextJS `10.0.3` in the meantime. I think they'll fix it soon.

Comment: The `sharp` dependency has been removed in [v10.0.8](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v10.0.8). Works good now. Thanks!

Comment: Would recommend not to update to 10.0.8 for the time being as there is a memory leak with the next/image component.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. It was happening to me because I have the Apple M1 Mac. I solved the error installing Homebrew, and after that, I had to install 'lipvips' using `Brew install vips`. Then, inside my project, `npm install sharp`, and finally,  I run `npm run build` and it worked fine for me. I Hope It works for you!

Comment: Would you know if there's a Windows version of this solution that works without full admin rights to the machine? I'm on a corporate system here. So no fetching anything directly from GitHub URLs in the terminal, which is exactly what the sharp install keeps trying to do hence fails.

Comment: You save me!!! Thank you very much! I have a macbook air m1 too and this error was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on mac m1. I downgraded node version to 14 and now it works